# when I try to use Oracle Statistics my cost grows?

Tags: oracle, optimization, statistics

I have a big query on for tables and I want to optimize it.

The weird part is that when I get the execution plan without statistics it says something like 1.2M. however if I get statistics for one of the tables involved in the query, my cost lowers to 4k. But if I ask for statistics in the other tables the cost grows to 50k, so I am not sure what's happening.

Can anyone explain a reason why giving more statistics actually increases query cost?

Comment: When asking about optimizer, the version is VERY important. What version are you asking about?

Comment: mmmm not shure, i use oracle 10g

Comment: How exactly are you gathering the stats? List statements literally.

Comment: I use sqldeveloper so i right click on the table, select statistics=> gather statistics for 100% . and to erase the statistics I use dbms_stats.delete_schema_stats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cost Based Optimiser uses as much information as you can give it in order to calculate the cost of a plan. If you update (i.e. change) the statistics it uses, then obviously that will change the calculated cost of the plan.

It's not actually the gathering of stats that causes the cost to grow - it's how those stats have changed (whether up or down) that causes the calculated cost to change.

In the absence of statistics, Oracle may use heuristics, guesswork or a quick sample of the data (depending on the settings in your instance).

Generally, the better (more accurate or representative) the statistics, the more accurate the cost calculation.

Comment: okey, three thingsi understand what your saying, but i think my problem is a bit different. The thing is that im just trying to optimize a query (that runs really, really slow) so I gather the statistics for my schema

Comment: @pictureyournews - yes, and your point is?  The COST in an Explain Plan is the Optimizer's *guess* at the expense of executing a query; its guess gets more accurate with fresher statistics.  The important thing is: does your query run quicker now you've gathered statistics on the selected tables?

Comment: no, thats the problem. This is what happens:  First, I delete all statistics and ask for the cost, it is aprox 1.2M, then I generate statistics for one table, the cost lowers to 4k, then I gather statistics for another table and the cost goes up to 7.5k, so im not shure whats happening. My question is, why does the cost increase when I get more statistics?

Comment: (Maby im not being clear on this, but the statistics are fresh because Im just testing for ways to optimize the query and no one is updating or inserting on the tables.... im sorry if I haven't been clear)

Comment: @pictureyournews: don't muck around with varying stats in order to try to optimize a query. Get the stats as good as possible, then look at your query. See if the query returns the number of records that the CBO thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

The cost based optimizer has it's challenges. There are rounding errors that can have quite an impact on decisions that it makes. This is one of the reasons that SQL Plan Stability, introduced in 11g is so nice. Forget about 10g, if you can, or prepare for long debugging sessions.

At the first use, a plan is generated based on the current statistics and executed. If SQL is repeated, the SQL and the plan are stored in a baseline. In the maintenance window, the most expensive plans are re evaluated and in many cases, a better plan can be provided. This is possible because at runtime, the optimizer is limited in the time it is given to search for a plan. In the maintenance window, a lot more time can be spent to find the best plan.

In 11g the peeking is also fixed and a single SQL can now have multiple plans, based on the values of the bind variables.
The query cost is based on many factors, where IO is a very important factor.
How are your tables filled and where are the high water marks located? A table that is filled and emptied constantly can have it's high watermark far away....

There are lots of bugs in the optimizer, lots of options, controlled by hidden parameters. You could try to use them to tweek the behaviour. Upgrading to 11g might be a lot smarter as it solves lots of performance problems for many applications.